# Displayed values are not what they should be

Tags: mysql, sql

There are 2 tables ost_ticket and ost_ticket_action_history.

```
  create table ost_ticket(
ticket_id int not null PRIMARY KEY,
created timestamp,
staff bool,
status varchar(50),
city_id int
);
create table ost_ticket_action_history(
    ticket_id int not null,
    action_id int not null PRIMARY KEY,
    action_name varchar(50),
    started timestamp,
    FOREIGN KEY(ticket_id) REFERENCES ost_ticket(ticket_id)
);
```

In the ost_ticket_action_history table the data is:

```
  INSERT INTO newdb.ost_ticket_action_history (ticket_id, action_id, action_name, started) VALUES (1, 1, 'Consultation', '2022-01-06 18:30:29');
INSERT INTO newdb.ost_ticket_action_history (ticket_id, action_id, action_name, started) VALUES (2, 2, 'Bank Application', '2022-02-06 18:30:45');
INSERT INTO newdb.ost_ticket_action_history (ticket_id, action_id, action_name, started) VALUES (3, 3, 'Consultation', '2022-05-06 18:42:48');
```

In the ost_ticket table the data is:

```
INSERT INTO newdb.ost_ticket (ticket_id, created, staff, status, city_id) VALUES (1, '2022-04-04 18:26:41', 1, 'open', 2);
INSERT INTO newdb.ost_ticket (ticket_id, created, staff, status, city_id) VALUES (2, '2022-05-05 18:30:48', 0, 'open', 3);
INSERT INTO newdb.ost_ticket (ticket_id, created, staff, status, city_id) VALUES (3, '2022-04-06 18:42:53', 1, 'open', 4);
```

***My task is to get the conversion from the “Consultation” stage to the “Bank Application” stage broken down by months (based on the start date of the “Bank Application” stage)***.Conversion is calculated according to the following formula: (number of applications with the “Bank Application” stage / number of applications with the “Consultation” stage) * 100%.

[image: Tables schema]

My request is like this:

```
select SUM(action_name='Bank Application')/SUM(action_name='Consultation') * 2 as 'Conversion' from ost_ticket_action_history JOIN ost_ticket ot on ot.ticket_id = ost_ticket_action_history.ticket_id where status = 'open' and created > '2020 -01-01 00:00:00' group by action_name,started having action_name = 'Bank Application';
```

As a result I get:

[image: Tables schema]

Another query:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN b.ticket_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) / COUNT(*) conversion,
    YEAR(a.started) AS 'year',
    MONTH(a.started) AS 'month'
FROM
    ost_ticket_action_history a
        LEFT JOIN
    ost_ticket_action_history b ON a.ticket_id = b.ticket_id
        AND b.action_name = 'Bank Application'
WHERE
    a.action_name = 'Consultation'
        AND a.status = 'open'
        AND a.created > '2020-01-01 00:00:00'
GROUP BY YEAR(a.started) , MONTH(a.started)
```

I apologize if I didn't write very clearly. Please explain what to do.

Comment: without data, we can' really determine the cause, so read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and make a [mre]

Comment: Your problem is that you habe no b rows that match your condition and so b is NULL, ergo all results are NULL

Comment: i added the minimum data  @nbk do you have enough of them?

Comment: is there a problem with the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Like I explained in my comment, you exclude rows with your having clause.

I will show you in the next how to debug.

First check what the raw result of the select query is.

As you see, when you remove the `GROUP BY` and see what you actually get is only 1 row with bank application, because the having clause excludes all other rows

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM
    ost_ticket_action_history
JOIN
    ost_ticket ot ON ot.ticket_id = ost_ticket_action_history.ticket_id
WHERE
    status = 'open'
    AND created > '2020-01-01 00:00:00'
GROUP BY 
    action_name, started
HAVING 
    action_name = 'Bank Application';
```

Output:

| ticket_id | action_id | action_name | started | ticket_id | created | staff | status | city_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 | Bank Application | 2022-02-06 18:30:45 | 2 | 2022-05-05 18:30:48 | 0 | open | 3 |

Second step, see what the result set is without calculating anything.

As you can see you make a division with 0, what you have learned in school, is forbidden, hat is why you have as result set NULL

> ```
> SELECT 
>  
>  SUM(action_name = 'Bank Application') 
>  #/
>  ,SUM(action_name = 'Consultation') * 2 AS 'Conversion'
> FROM
>     ost_ticket_action_history
>         JOIN
>     ost_ticket ot ON ot.ticket_id = ost_ticket_action_history.ticket_id
> WHERE
>     status = 'open'
>         AND created > '2020-01-01 00:00:00'
> GROUP BY action_name , started
> HAVING action_name = 'Bank Application';
> ```

> ```
> SUM(action_name = 'Bank Application') | Conversion
> ------------------------------------: | ---------:
>                                     1 |          0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=29a1622ae7c2a513fe9df267ab49d2e1)*

#Third what you can do exclude a division with 0, here i didn't remove all othe rows as this is only for emphasis

> ```
> SELECT 
>  
>  SUM(action_name = 'Bank Application') 
>  /
>  SUM(action_name = 'Consultation') * 2 AS 'Conversion'
> FROM
>     ost_ticket_action_history
>         JOIN
>     ost_ticket ot ON ot.ticket_id = ost_ticket_action_history.ticket_id
> WHERE
>     status = 'open'
>         AND created > '2020-01-01 00:00:00'
> GROUP BY action_name , started
> HAVING SUM(action_name = 'Consultation') > 0;
> ```

> ```
> | Conversion |
> | ---------: |
> |     0.0000 |
> |     0.0000 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=16314aa8d846ca39e26ff5fcc0842f2d)*

Final words,
If you get a strange result, simply go  back remove everything that doesn't matter and try to get all values, so hat you can check your math